# Program that allows user to search a sorted list of names freezes up

Tags: c

I'm trying write a program that takes a list of names, sorts those names, and allows the user to search for a name from that list. The program compiles, but once the user has entered "y" to search for a name and has entered the name he wishes to search for, the program just freezes.

I appreciate any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_NAMES 8
#define NAME_SIZE 5

void printNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int size);
void bubbleSortNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int last);
bool binarySearchNames(char list[][NAME_SIZE], int end, char target[], int *location);

int main()
{
    char nameList[NUM_OF_NAMES][NAME_SIZE] = {"Bob", "Sue", "Jake","Rod", "Jon", 
                                              "Ash", "Deb", "Kay"};
    char searchText[NAME_SIZE];
    char userChoice;
    int searchLocation;

    printf("\n\n\nLIST BEFORE SORTING\n");    
    printNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES);
    bubbleSortNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES);

    printf("\n\n\nLIST AFTER SORTING\n");
    printNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES);

    printf("\n\n\nWould you like to search for a name? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c", &userChoice);

    while(userChoice == 'y')
    {
        printf("\n\n\nPlease try to search for a name: ");
    scanf("%c", searchText);

    if(!(binarySearchNames(nameList, NUM_OF_NAMES, searchText, &searchLocation)))
            printf("\n\n\nThe name %c was not found.\n", searchText); 
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\nThe name %s was found at location %d!", searchText, 
                   searchLocation);
    }
    }

    printf("\n\n\nThank you for using this program.\n\n\n");

    return 0;
}

/********************************
Prints the names from the array.
********************************/
void printNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int size)
{
    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < size; index++)
        puts(names[index]);

    return;
}

/*******************************
Sorts the names from the array.
*******************************/
void bubbleSortNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int last)
{
    char temp[NAME_SIZE];
    int current;
    int walker;

    for(current = 0; current < last; current++)
    {
        for(walker = last; walker > current; walker--)
        {
            if(strcmp(names[walker], names[walker - 1]) < 0)
        {
                strncpy(temp, names[walker - 1], sizeof(temp) - 1);
        strncpy(names[walker - 1], names[walker], sizeof(names[walker - 1]) 
                        -  1);
        strncpy(names[walker], temp, sizeof(names[walker]) - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

/*********************************
Searches for names to be printed.
*********************************/
bool binarySearchNames(char list[][NAME_SIZE], int end, char target[], int* location)
{
    int first = 0,
        last,
        mid;

    last = end;   

    while(first <= last);
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;

    if(strcmp(target, list[mid] > 0) 
        first = mid + 1;
    else if(strcmp(target, list[mid]) < 0)
        last = mid - 1;
    else
        first = last +  1;
    }

    *location = mid + 1;

    return (strcmp(target, list[mid]) == 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(strcmp(target, list[mid] > 0))
```

into this:

```
if(strcmp(target, list[mid]) > 0)
```

Mind the parentheses (and maybe consider getting an editor that highlights matching parentheses).